# OpenGL ES hangs on x86_64 emulator

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I have an OpenGL-based app which hangs when run on the native emulator the moment the user presses a button. The main thread gets stuck in a glTexSubImage2D call which, as far as I can see, is internally writing to a socket (QemuPipeStream::writeFully) that connects to some server process within the emulator:

```
lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #1: tid = 5036, 0xb73b2706 libc.so`write + 22, name = 'foo.bar', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0xb73b2706 libc.so`write + 22
    frame #1: 0xabf81611 libOpenglSystemCommon.so`QemuPipeStream::writeFully(void const*, unsigned int) + 97
    frame #2: 0xab8069bf libGLESv2_enc.so`??? + 273
    frame #3: 0xab7a5668 libGLESv2_emulation.so`glTexSubImage2D + 120
    frame #4: 0xa41287a2 libbeeb.so`Beeb_drawFrame + 98
    frame #5: 0xa41110d0 libbeeb.so`Java_libbeeb_BeebView_bbcDrawFrame + 32
  * frame #6: 0xa4a56765 base.odex`int libbeeb.BeebView.bbcDrawFrame() + 105 at BeebView.java:0
    frame #7: 0xa4a56ab5 base.odex`void libbeeb.BeebView.videoCallback() + 57 at BeebView.java:28
    frame #8: 0xb3a17a83 libart.so`art_quick_invoke_stub + 339
    frame #9: 0xb3a235c5 libart.so`art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*) + 213
    frame #10: 0xb3dec47d libart.so`.L1360 + 74
    frame #11: 0xb3cd3216 libart.so`art::JNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*) + 589
```

The app is slightly unusual in that it does all its OpenGL rendering from it's main thread. This is because it is not a game and keeping it single-threaded makes a lot more sense than introducing a dedicated render thread and associated sync.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a bug in Google/Intel's x86 Android emulators, as the issue does not occur on Genymotion or hardware.